# Add a character count to admin inputs and textareas

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I'd like to add a character count to every input and text area in the product details page in my Magento store admin.

I'm used to jQuery but would rather use the default Prototype library for this if possible. I found this code somewhere which does the trick for the short description and description fields specifically, using their ID's to target them:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

Element.insert( $('short_description').up().next().down('span'), { 
    'after': "<div id='short_description_counter'>Char count: <span id='short_description_counter_num'>"+$('short_description').getValue().length+"</span></div>"
});
Element.insert( $('description').up().next().down('span'), { 
    'after': "<div id='description_counter'>Char count: <span id='description_counter_num'>"+$('description').getValue().length+"</span></div>"
});

Event.observe('short_description', 'keyup', function(event) {   $("short_description_counter_num").update(this.getValue().length);  });
Event.observe('description', 'keyup', function(event) { $("description_counter_num").update(this.getValue().length);    });
});
```

Can someone with Prototype experience tell me how to edit this so that it runs on every input and textarea, so not specifying an ID? I'm presuming there's some each(function) that can be used.

UPDATE:
Here's the current code working on a textarea, specified by it's ID - http://jsbin.com/isisur/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My prototype is rusty but I *think* this will work:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('input[type="text"], textarea').each( function(i) {
        var my_id = $(i).readAttribute('id');
        $(i).insert({ 
            'after': "<div id='"+my_id+"_counter'>Char count: <span id='"+my_id+"_counter_num'>"+$(i).getValue().length+"</span></div>"
        });
        $(i).observe('keyup', function(e) {
            $(my_id+"_counter_num").update($(this).getValue().length);
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gDvsG/)

Comment: Cheers for the attempt! Throwing an error though: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'down' of undefined"*

Comment: I don't suppose you can update the question with a snippet of HTML that shows a text input and/or textarea and surrounding HTML code for reference?

Comment: That was *very* helpful. Check out my updated answer with working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

A more fexible code, that works with every field with classes `validate-length` and `maximum-length-XXX`:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    Element.addMethods({
        prepare_for_countdown: function(element) {
            var elm = $(element);
            if(!elm.retrieve('counter')) {
                var counter = new Element('span');
                elm.next('.note').insert(counter);
                elm.store('counter', counter);
                var maxLen = elm.className.match(/maximum-length-(\d+)/)[1];
                elm.store('maxLen', maxLen);
            }
            return elm;
        },
        countdown: function(element) {
            var elm = $(element);
            var curLen = elm.getValue().length;
            var maxLen = elm.retrieve('maxLen');
            var count  = maxLen - curLen;
            var counter = elm.retrieve('counter');
            if (curLen >= maxLen) {
                counter.update(' (' + count + ')').setStyle({'color': 'red'});
            } else {
                counter.update(' (+' + count + ')').setStyle({'color': 'green'});
            }
            return elm;
        }
    });

    $$('.validate-length').invoke('prepare_for_countdown').invoke('countdown');

    document.on('keyup', '.validate-length', function(evt, elm) {
        elm.countdown();
    });
});
```

From: [Prototype.js 1.7 uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLInputElement]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431611/prototype-js-1-7-uncaught-exception-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-obj/44436408#44436408)